# Application to know where certain piece of data in webpage came from

Tags: web-development, web-browser

Say I'm looking at a web page that makes a ton of AJAX requests to get data to populate the DOM. What I want to do is to, in the browser, select a certain piece of data (e.g. name of user) and get back the request that was used to obtain that piece of data.

This sounds like an application that would be hard to develop but not impossible. Anyone knows something that does this, or at least, something similar?